# Data bound Repeater in a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have a friends list page which displays 2 user controls.
This first control displays all current friends, while the other displays current friend requests.

The user controls load in this order:

**-Current Friends**
**-Friend Requests**

They each search the DB in almost the same manner, use the same structure of `List<>`, and bind to very similar `Repeaters`.

The current issue I'm getting is this:

```
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
```

Yet I am Opening the connection before every reader, and closing it after use. Due to the similarities; I will post one of the `UserControl`'s code. Will post more on request.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetFriend();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current friends
    /// </summary>
    private void GetFriend()
    {
        try
        {
            List<FriendRequests> friendRequest = new List<FriendRequests>();

            // Get friend added by another
            const string strSql = "SELECT [id], [origionalId], [dateFriendAdded] FROM vwMemberFriendStatus WHERE contactId=@member AND accepted=1";

            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, DataConn.Connect()) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

            sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@member", SqlDbType.Int)).Value =
                SiteSession.Current.NicknameId;

            SqlDataReader rdr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();


            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                friendRequest.Add(new FriendRequests
                {
                    IsOrigional = false,
                    FriendId = rdr["id"].ToString(),
                    FriendName = Member.GetMemberName(rdr["origionalId"].ToString()),
                    DateAdded = DateTime.Parse(rdr["dateFriendAdded"].ToString()).ToString("dd MMMM yy")
                });
            }

            rptFriend.DataSource = friendRequest;
            rptFriend.DataBind();

            rdr.Close();
            DataConn.Disconnect();
            Response.Write("Current - Other <br/>");
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Response.Write("Current / Other: " + f.Message + "<br/>");
        }

        try
        {
            List<FriendRequests> friendRequest = new List<FriendRequests>();

            // Get friend added by self
            const string strSql =
                        "SELECT [id], [contactId], [dateFriendAdded] FROM vwMemberFriendStatus WHERE origionalId=@member AND accepted=1";

            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, DataConn.Connect()) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

            sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@member", SqlDbType.Int)).Value =
                SiteSession.Current.NicknameId;

            SqlDataReader rdr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                friendRequest.Add(new FriendRequests
                {
                    IsOrigional = true,
                    FriendId = rdr["id"].ToString(),
                    FriendName = Member.GetMemberName(rdr["contactId"].ToString()),
                    DateAdded = DateTime.Parse(rdr["dateFriendAdded"].ToString()).ToString("dd MMMM yy")
                });
            }

            rptFriend.DataSource = friendRequest;
            rptFriend.DataBind();

            rdr.Close();
            DataConn.Disconnect();
            Response.Write("Current - Self <br/>");
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Response.Write("Current / Self: " + f.Message + "<br/>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line throws that error?  Also, does the error happen every time you run the page, or just sometimes?  In other words, is it consistently repeatable?

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `DataConn` class? It looks like the connection is handled in there.